# How to change file's names by folder?

Tags: shell, terminal

I have a folder with about 1,000 files look like this:

```
$ awk '{print $9}' folder
1003ns_cells_found.fcs
1003pi_cells_found.fcs
1007ns_cells_found.fcs
1007pi_cells_found.fcs
1029ns_cells_found.fcs
1029pi_cells_found.fcs
1041nsA_cells_found.fcs
```

And I have another ID file like this:

```
$ head -5 ID
1003 BD2188
1003 BD2188
1007 BD2116
1007 BD2116
1029 BD2012
```

I would replace the ID numbers of all files in folder with the second column of the ID file. Does anyone know how to realize it through Terminal/Shell?

Comment: your sample data seems to "line-up" between the two files. Is that intended OR do you want just one line like `1003 BC2188` in your ID file? Put another way, does your ID file also have about 1000 lines in it? ALSO please edit your question to include expected sample output given those inputs. When you topic line says "change files ..." do you want to issue `mv` or `rename` cmds. like `mv 1003ns_cells_found.fcs BD2188ns_cells_found.fcs` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple script should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls ./folder | while read line; do
cat ID | awk -v x=${line:0:4} 'x==$1 {printf "%s", $2; exit}'
echo -e "${line:4}";
done
```

The folder structure looks like this:

```
$ find
.
./ID <-- file with the IDs
./folder
./folder/1003pi_cells_found.fcs
./folder/1041nsA_cells_found.fcs
./folder/1007pi_cells_found.fcs
./folder/1007ns_cells_found.fcs
./folder/1029pi_cells_found.fcs
./folder/1003ns_cells_found.fcs
./folder/1029ns_cells_found.fcs
./script <-- script to execute
```

Output:

```
BD2188ns_cells_found.fcs
BD2188pi_cells_found.fcs
BD2116ns_cells_found.fcs
BD2116pi_cells_found.fcs
BD2012ns_cells_found.fcs
BD2012pi_cells_found.fcs
nsA_cells_found.fcs
```

Last one is empty because `1041` is not found in the file `ID`.